# Adding an Open Source Repository - inconsistent UX

Tags: bug, developer-story

Adding a new Open Source thing you did recently with the new developer story is pretty slick.  Just click and you're sorted.

[image]

If you want to **edit** it though...that's going to involve some scrolling.

[image]

There's...there's more past that cutoff, but I can't be bothered to paste it *all*.

This UX concerns me for a few reasons:

- I can't edit any of the information that I had entered in that was custom to the project description, which I find inconvenient and somewhat misleading.  If I want to add my own little blurb here, why can't I?  I'm given the option to.
- Updating the information is strange in that I have to physically scroll through a whole bunch of options.  I feel a select drop down would be better in this case, to at least save the scrolling.
- What if I have work on Bitbucket and GitHub?  How would that look then?  (I don't unfortunately, but I could envision scenarios where work one has contributed to would be in multiple places.)

Could this get looked into?

Comment: Thanks for the report, yes we'll look into this :)